# Formatting a long line of nested method calls in Java

Tags: java, android

I am unsure as to how I should break up this long line of code (has been further indented by conditional and switch blocking):

```
titleText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COLUMN_NAME)));
```

it is my understanding that the line should be broken up by an 8 space indent after each method argument's outermost method call to the inner most arguments method call, until the next line fits:

```
titleText.setText(cursor
        .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COLUMN_NAME)));
```

but according to this post [Formatting multiple arguments passed to a function in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023391/formatting-multiple-arguments-passed-to-a-function-in-java), the aforementioned method is only a default and the proper amount of space is until you are in-line with the first argument of the above line

```
titleText.setText(cursor
                 .getString(cursor
                           .getColumnIndex(MovieContract
                                          .TrailerEntry
                                          .COLUMN_NAME)));
```

However, I feel as though I have never seen this in production code. Or perhaps I should just use temp variables to break out this line into multiple java statements?

**EDIT**
Thanks to shmosel for pointing out that the above link should not have been used to reference the problem as the logic is unrelated.

Comment: I would separate it in multiple statements, much easier to debug.

Comment: What did you see in the linked post to suggest this formatting? It's not even the same scenario. That post is discussing multiple arguments and you're asking about nested method calls.

Comment: Aslong as you dont work for a company with a specific code standard just being consistent is enough. If you´re coding a personal project then make sure you can read it. And if you are coding for a company make sure it´s consistent with the company´s current codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to nest, I would do it like this:

```
titleText.setText(
        cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(
                        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COLUMN_NAME)));
```

However, this gets bloated pretty fast. Ideally, you want to avoid a lot of nesting and break up your statement using temporary variables. It makes your code cleaner and more explicit:

```
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COLUMN_NAME);
titleText.setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
```

Of course, there various ways to formulate the above. At the end of the day it's all a matter of taste and, more importantly, convention. If you're looking for specific guidelines, consider Google's [Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.5.1-line-wrapping-where-to-break) or [*The Elements of Java Style*](http://a.co/1jBAIS4).

Comment: Well, I would keep a statement as much on one line as possible, provided it's not *too* long. For example – it's kinda hard to explain it in the comment section because of the formatting restriction –, I would keep it like this: `int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COLUMN_NAME);`

Comment: @MCEmperor I get your point, but the definition of "too long" is pretty subjective. I chose to go with a more restrictive definition partly because of the SO post width and also to demonstrate a mixed approach to formatting.

Comment: I agree with you on that. However, many people stick to the default right margin line of Netbeans or Eclipse, so one can say it's a common rule for when a statement should be split into multiple lines.